# TypeError: main() missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python

I just started studying UDF's and I can't get my code to work and I am unsure what I did wrong, anyone know how to fix this?

I am getting this error
line 55, in 
main()
TypeError: main() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'word1', 'word2', and 'word3'

my code looks like this

```
import random

def get_determiner(amount):
    if amount == 1:
        determiner = ['a', 'one', 'the']
    else:
        determiner = ['those', 'some', 'many', 'the']
    word1 = random.choice(determiner)
    return word1

def get_noun(amount):
    if amount == 1:
        noun = ["bird", "boy", "car", "cat", "child",
        "dog", "girl", "man", "rabbit", "woman"]
    else:
        noun = ["birds", "boys", "cars", "cats", "children",
        "dogs", "girls", "men", "rabbits", "women"]

    word2 = random.choice(noun)
    return word2

def get_verb(amount, tense):
    if tense == 'past':
        verb = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought",
        "ran", "slept", "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
    elif tense == 'past' and amount == 1:
        verb = ["drinks", "eats", "grows", "laughs", "thinks",
        "runs", "sleeps", "talks", "walks", "writes"]
    elif tense == 'past' and amount != 1:
        verb =["drink", "eat", "grow", "laugh", "think",
        "run", "sleep", "talk", "walk", "write"]
    elif tense == 'future':
        verb =["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh",
        "will think", "will run", "will sleep", "will talk",
        "will walk", "will write"]
    
    word3 = random.choice(verb)
    return word3

def main():

    get_determiner(word1)
    get_noun(word2)
    get_verb(word3)

    amount = input('how many things are there? ')
    tense = input('Past, present or future? ')
    first = word1.capitalize()

    print(f'{first} {word2} {word3}')

main()
```

Comment: replace last line with **main()**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. That said, there are several other problems with this code. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. It's not clear to me, however, that you understand how calling a function works. If you are confused about it, please try following a tutorial. If you do understand, then think about it more clearly: where should e.g. the `amount` parameter for `get_determiner` come from? What should happen first - asking the user for this information, or calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

def get_determiner(amount):
    if amount == 1:
        determiner = ['a', 'one', 'the']
    else:
        determiner = ['those', 'some', 'many', 'the']
    word1 = random.choice(determiner)
    return word1

def get_noun(amount):
    if amount == 1:
        noun = ["bird", "boy", "car", "cat", "child",
        "dog", "girl", "man", "rabbit", "woman"]
    else:
        noun = ["birds", "boys", "cars", "cats", "children",
        "dogs", "girls", "men", "rabbits", "women"]

    word2 = random.choice(noun)
    return word2

def get_verb(amount, tense):
    if tense == 'past':
        verb = ["drank", "ate", "grew", "laughed", "thought",
        "ran", "slept", "talked", "walked", "wrote"]
    elif tense == 'past' and amount == 1:
        verb = ["drinks", "eats", "grows", "laughs", "thinks",
        "runs", "sleeps", "talks", "walks", "writes"]
    elif tense == 'past' and amount != 1:
        verb =["drink", "eat", "grow", "laugh", "think",
        "run", "sleep", "talk", "walk", "write"]
    elif tense == 'future':
        verb =["will drink", "will eat", "will grow", "will laugh",
        "will think", "will run", "will sleep", "will talk",
        "will walk", "will write"]
    
    word3 = random.choice(verb)
    return word3

def main():



    amount = input('how many things are there? ')
    tense = input('Past, present or future? ')
    word1 = get_determiner(amount)
    word2 = get_noun(amount)
    word3 = get_verb(amount, tense)
    first = word1.capitalize()

    print(f'{first} {word2} {word3}')

    
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using 3 variables `word1 word2 word3` inside `main()` , but `main` doesn't know who these variables are, so either define the three of them as global variables (highly discouraged in programming), pass them as arguments to `main()` ,or define them inside `main()`.

Second, `print()` is a function that doesn't return anything, so passing `print()` to `main()` is like passing `None` type to a function. It doesn't make much sense.

Third, your `get_verb()` takes two arguments, but you only pass one. Pass the correct arguments or use a default value for the other argument.

Fourth, when calling your three functions inside `main()` you are not storing the return in any variable, it's almost like you didn't call them.

Fix these and try again, because the error you should be getting is a `NameError: name 'first' is not defined` and not a `TypeError`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks now I just have to figure out how to fix the name error.

Comment: Just define the variables inside the function (like in Raj Patel's answer), pass them as arguments, or make them global (don't do that one).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameters in **main** function when it does not have any. [Learn more about arguments and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169033/parameter-vs-argument-python)

So you can change your main function

```
def main(word1, word2, word3):
….
```

And call the main function

```
main('word1', 'word2', 'word3')
```