# Is it possible to call a callback function which may declare no arguments but then pass some arguments at call time without raising exception?

Tags: python, callback

Is it possible to have the below code without raising an exception?
The `hello` function represents code outside my control. It is only here for the sake of clarity.

```
def hello():
    print("hellowed")

def callsCallback(callback):
    callback(*["dd"])

callsCallback(hello)
```

The idea is for a library to receive a callback function for when something happens. For backwards compatibility, the function being called may or may not receive parameters.

I'm aware of this answer: [How can I find the number of arguments of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188411) but I'd rather avoid inspection, if I can.

Comment: Use `def hello(*args)` for variable number of args.

Comment: `def hello()` is from outside my code

Comment: You can't avoid inspection then. Python isn't javascript, it's not going to ignore arguments a function doesn't expect.

Comment: You could make a wrapper function stripping unwanted arguments.

Comment: @SilverSlash I'm just trying to make sure I did my research right.

Comment: @VPfB How do I know which arguments are not wanted, then? Only inspection, right?

Comment: @brunoais The title says no arguments. But in general either you know or you do the inspection.

Comment: @VPfB Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you used `*args` in a wrapper function then it would never throw an exception because of the incorrect number of arguments.

```
def hello():
    print("hellowed")

def wrapper(f):
    def g(*args):
        f() 
    return g

def callsCallback(callback):
    callback = wrapper(callback)
    callback(*["dd"])

callsCallback(hello)
```

You could use a decorator style function. This may be overkill for what you want to do.

If you don't know ahead of time how many arguments `hello` takes, you would have to introspect as you suggested to call the function appropriately.

Comment: `def hello()` is from outside my code. I added redundancy to that fact to make the question more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer above to make it more closer to what you want.

Comment: You sure it is correct? The wrapper function doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say `return g`. I've edited the above answer.

Comment: Still doesn't do what I need but it does something useful.