# Determine if argument into method is "self"

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the question [How can I find the number of arguments of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/847936/1079075) code is given showing how to using `inspect.getfullargspec` to get information of a function. However, is there any way to verify whether one of the arguments for the function is `self`? Is it possible to identify if the first method argument is `self` Python 2, by somehow check if the first argument of a given function is a reference to the method's object?

For example, the first argument in the function `step` is technically `self` even though someone has decided to be evil and rename `self` to `what`.

```
class TestNode(object):

    def __init__(what, bias=0):
        what.bias = bias

    def update(what, t, x):
        return t / x * what.bias
```

However, the first argument in the function `lambda self: self+1` despite someone being evil and naming an argument `self` is not actually the `self` using in Python objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we take a step back from argument inspection and think of this question as a question of determining if a function is a method or not. We can do this with the [`inspect.ismethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) function:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
...
>>> inspect.ismethod(Foo().bar)
True
```

If the function is a bound method we can safely assume that the first passed argument to this method will be `self`.

Note that in Python 2.X, this will return True for unbound methods (e.g. `Foo.bar`) whereas in 3.X it will return True only if the method is bound.

We can take this one step further by using [getmembers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) and actually determine what the value of `self` is for this bound method:

```
>>> dict(inspect.getmembers(Foo()))["bar"].__self__
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f601eb50a58>
```

Which returns the `Foo()` instance that this `bar` method is bound to. In Python 2.X, `__self__` will be `None` if the instance is unbound, which is how you differentiate between bound and unbound methods.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is not a special argument. The name `self` has nothing special at all - It is a normal argument just like the others, the only reason it is named `self` is convention between the programmers.

There is no way you can differentiate a `self` argument from other arguments, because it is not different at all!

What you can do is check if the function is member of a class - then it becomes a method and will get the instance as first parameter automatically - this is done by the **metaclass descriptors** as you can see [here in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

if `inspect.ismethod()` returns `True` then the first parameter passed to the function will be the instance, regardless of the name.