# Dynamically find how many variables are in a defined function in Python

Tags: python

## Problem

Assume that a function is defined:

```
def add_func(a, b):
  return a + b
```

I would like to dynamically find out how many variables `add_func` can take in. For example, by using some attributes of the function such as

```
> add_func.__num_variables__
```

I have looked up all the attributes of the defined function, but none of the attributes give me the information that I need.

```
> dir(add_func)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Would appreciate

## Why

A little explanation on why I have to dynamically find out how many variables are in a function. The function is provided by a customer, and the function name is always the same, but the number of variables can updated by customer. On my side, I need to create a web page (form), which should have as many inputs as the number of the variables in the function. Theoretically I can force the customer to maintain a config file, but before that I'd like to explore if Python as a scripting language is able to support my use case.

Comment: Why not have a dynamic number of arguments for your function?

Comment: use a dict instead of loose variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the number of arguments of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847936/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-python-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get method parameter names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/how-to-get-method-parameter-names)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
print(add_function.__code__.co_varnames)
```

Comment: add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get you a dictionary for the parameters present.

```
from inspect import signature
sig=signature(add_func)
print(dict(sig.parameters))
```

**Expected Output**

`{'a': <Parameter "a">, 'b': <Parameter "b">}`

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847936/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-python-function):

import signature module from inspect library:

```
from inspect import signature
```

create a functions (in this case it takes 2 arguments)

```
def test(a, b):
    pass
```

assign the function to the module signature and store in a variable (here sig)

```
sig = signature(test)
```

print to check the arguments passed inside the function
**output should be**

```
print(sig)
(a, b)
```

Comment: add some explanation to your code.

Comment: Okay okay, just done :)