# Call Python function passed as parameter without knowing if it takes any parameters

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I have a project in which I need to do some things, call one of a few functions, and then do some other things:

```
def doCommand(function, parameter_for_function):
  # do a thing
  function(parameter_for_function)
  # do a thing
```

My problem is that I don't know if the function I will be passing will require a parameter of its own!

How can I allow my function to call both functions that have no parameters, and functions that have one?

Comment: You can introspect the function's signature as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/847936/3001761 to determine whether it needs the parameter or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method of handling this is probably along these lines:

```
def doCommand(function, *args, **kwargs):
  # do a thing
  function(*args, **kwargs)
  # do a thing
```

`*args` and `**kwargs` allow arbitrary arguments to be passed along to a method. As the name implies, these allow you to call `doCommand` with an arbitrary number of arguments and keyword arguments as well that get passed onto `function`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest explicitly saying that the function you take is one that's called with no parameters:

```
from typing import Callable

def doCommand(function: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
    # do a thing
    function()
    # do a thing
```

If the function needs parameters, it's then explicitly the responsibility of the `doCommand` caller to provide them, e.g. within a `lambda` expression:

```
def foo(param) -> None:
    print("foo: ", param)

doCommand(lambda: foo("bar"))
```

or a named wrapper function:

```
def foobar() -> None:
    foo("bar")

doCommand(foobar)
```