# extract the number and name of python method arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

How can I return the arguments of a function in a different module

```
#Module: functionss.py
def simple(a, b, c):
    print "does something"


#Module: extract.py
#load the called module and function
def get_args(module_name, function_name):
    modFile, modPath, modDesc = imp.find_module(module_name)
    mod = imp.load_module(module_name,modFile,modPath,modDesc)
    attr = getattr(mod, function_name)

#this is the part I don't get - how do I read the arguments
    return = attr.get_the_args()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     print get_args("functions.py", "simple")

 #this would ideally print [a, b, c]
```

Comment: What's wrong with reading the source?  It's Python -- you have the source, just read it.  What's preventing that?

Comment: Further, what's wrong with the `help()` function?  That usually tells you everything.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847936/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-python-function

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741950/programatically-determining-amount-of-parameters-a-function-requires-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getargspec) for the "heavy lifting" (introspecting a function).

Use `__import__` to import a module (given its **module name** -- `"functions.py"` is a terrible way to specify a module *name*;-).

Use `getattr(moduleobject, functionname)` to get the function object given module object and function name.