# How to fill function with any arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing

If I have a function that keeps changing number of arguments (adding, removing, refactoring etc.), how can I call this function in a test with arbitrary arguments? I just want to test that when a dependency returns True, the function itself raises a certain exception. Right now I have something like

```
dependency.return_value = True
self.assertRaises(Expcetion, function_being_tested, None, None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: It would not ever raise `Expcetion` exception probably :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not really sure that your unit tests are well designed if you need this kind of functionality, working with the information presented in this answer: [Programmatically determining amount of parameters a function requires - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741950/programatically-determining-amount-of-parameters-a-function-requires-python) we can see how we can get what you want.

```
import inspect

def call_wrapper(func):
    num_args = len(inspect.getargspec(func)[0])
    return func(*([None]*num_args))
```

And then your unit test becomes:

```
self.assertRaises(Expcetion, call_wrapper, function_being_tested)
```

Comment: Honestly, that seems like overkill but you're probably right that I should refactor

Comment: I mean you can certainly one-line it with `self.assertRaises(Exception, function_being_tested, *([None]*len(inpsect.getargspec(func)[0])))` but breaking it out lets you reuse it if you do the pattern frequently and makes what you're doing a little clearer to anyone else looking at the code.