# Pass functions as parameters that *sometimes* have parameters themselves

Tags: python

The following code works, however, I also want the currently commented line "perform(action1)" to work -- which would work if I comment-toggle line 3-4. This in turns, would stop the last line from working.

```
def perform(f):
    a = "A"
    #f()
    f(a)

def action1():
    print("No arg")

def action2(a):
        print(a)

#perform(action1)
perform(lambda a: action2(a=a))
```

I want function "perform" to receive functions as parameters that have a varying amount of parameters whose values are only assigned within "perform" and not known before.

Comment: Why would you want to "perform" a function that has no arguments with two arguments?

Comment: Does the code work?

Comment: By the way, `lambda: action1() == action1` just as `lambda a,b: action2(a=a,b=b) == action2`

Comment: You'd be better off trying to have a standardized interface, where all functions can be treated the same. I don't think you'll get a very clean way of deciding if a function accepts arguments or not; which you'd have to check to know if it's safe to pass arguments. I think you'd need to rely on a `try` for that, and that would likely require multiple `try`s; one for each possible argument set.

Comment: You’re going to have to give the correct arguments to `perform()` so wouldn’t it just be simpler all round to simply call `f()` with those arguments, and bion you get argument/parameter checking for free, i.e. normal function usage.

Comment: This seems like a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/291222)

Comment: I edited the question so it can hopefully be re-opened. @PeterWood

Comment: Is it @np8? I want a function that accepts functions with a different amount of parameters. That's my X. One could argue that my Y is a different code architecture then? Still, so X is technically not possible in Python?

Comment: Thanks @barny. To give context besides this mwe, parameter a is not known before as it changes within function perform. So that's why I came up with this design. So I guess I'll write some wrappers and stuff. Thanks.

Comment: It's very easy to pass different amount of parameters using [*args and **kwargs](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/). If that does not solve your problem, please write a toy example on what you are trying to achieve (with shown inputs and outputs),  i.e. a description of the problem at higher level.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks I'll try that. You are right, working with `try` s might work but doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the number of arguments of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847936/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-python-function)

Comment: @pixelated_icecream Why do you want *"a function that accepts functions with a different amount of parameters"*, when `perform` doesn't know how to prepare the parameters correctly? Why is that a requirement? That's your `Y`. What is `X`?

Comment: "So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things."

Answer (score -1):

Using the `inspect` module, you can retrieve the number of arguments the function takes in, the keyword ones, default values, ...

```py
import inspect
def function_get_n_args(func):
    return len(inspect.getfullargspec(func).args)
```

So your code would be :

```
def perform(f):
    a = "A"
    if function_get_n_args(f) == 1:
        f(a)
    else:
        f()

def action1():
    print("No arg")

def action2(a):
    print(a)

perform(action1)
# > No arg
perform(action2) # No need for lambda here but it would work too
# > A
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/741961/15860367)

Comment: `getargvalues` takes a frame created by a function call, not a function.

Comment: @chepner oops my bad, lemme edit this out :)